# How to create a new key:value pair from another key/value within the same object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I've run into an issue on the course I'm taking. I need to create a function that pulls two values from the same object and creates a new key/value. (Is there a better term to use besides key/value by the way?)

```
var customers = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
};

function createFullName(object) {
}
```

Im trying to make the function create a new key/value that is a string of the full name.

I've tried a for...in loop but I'm not sure how to get each iteration of the properties add to just one value. I can only do this sort of thing with an array.

Hope that made sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Give an example of sample input and output

Comment: You should be able to find this info in the most [basic tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and more specific to your question: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Answer (score 1):

To create the new key/value pair, just define it using the dot notation:

```js
var customers = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };

function createFullName(object) {
    object.fullName = object.firstName + " " + object.lastName;
}

createFullName(customers);

console.log(customers)
```

If you don't have a valid JavaScript identifier for the property (here I'm using `fullName`, which is) use a bracket notation instead.

Comment: *"If you have an invalid name for the property "* - If the property can be created with bracket notation then by definition its name is not invalid. (I know you were talking about names that don't work with dot notation, but that's not what you *said*.)

Comment: Is `full name`, with space, a valid name? I mean, what's the correct term here, if not "invalid"?

Comment: Yes, `'full name'` is a valid property name, but it doesn't work with dot notation.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the correct terminology, so I can edit the answer? A lot of people, apparently wrong, call names like this "invalid key names".

Comment: I think the usual term is "valid JS identifier". That's what [MDN uses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation). Saying "invalid key name" or "invalid property name" doesn't make sense, because it clearly is valid if you do `obj['full name']`. All I was looking for was something like "If the property name is not a valid JS identifier it can't be used with dot notation, so use bracket notation instead."